# Setting airflow web_server_ssl_cert and web_server_ssl_cert key Values.yaml in Helm (Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes-helm, airflow-webserver

I am running chart =>Helm Chart version 3.2.10 and Apache-airflow/airflow 2.6.2 on K8s ,

I am trying to set web_server_ssl_cert and web_server_ssl_key in the Values.yaml to map the airflow.cfg

Created secret => `kubectl create secret generic web-cert-and-key --from-file=server.key --from-file=server.crt`

Added this line to my Values.yaml

`

```
env: 
  - name: web_server_ssl_cert
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: web-cert-and-key
        key: server.crt
  - name: web_server_ssl_cert
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: web-cert-and-key
        key: server.key
```

I am not particular sure, If I am doing the right thing I am getting the error

```
`

Error: UPGRADE FAILED: values don't meet the specifications of the schema(s) in the following chart(s):
airflow:
- webserver.env.0: value is required
- webserver.env.0: Additional property valueFrom is not allowed
- webserver.env.1: value is required
- webserver.env.1: Additional property valueFrom is not allowed

helm.go:84: [debug] values don't meet the specifications of the schema(s) in the following chart(s):
airflow:
- webserver.env.0: value is required
- webserver.env.0: Additional property valueFrom is not allowed
- webserver.env.1: value is required
- webserver.env.1: Additional property valueFrom is not allowed
```

See value.json.schema

https://github.com/ogbene23/SupplychainERP/blob/master/values.schema.json

Comment: check there will be values.schema.json, which will give you some idea. If possible update your question with it.

Comment: Thank  you Mohammed , the schema is quite length and exceeds the the words limit, I have added it as  github link to the question

Comment: @Mohammed I saw what the problem was, My only concern is that I do want to hardcode certifcate values and key , but the env  is refusing selecting from K8s secret

Comment: getting 404 when i access github link